# Finding the derivative of an integral involving $e^{t^4}$.

Tags: integration, derivatives

Find the derivative of this fucntion:

$$F(x)=\int_{x}^{x^2} e^{t^4} dt $$

I have no idea how to do this question.

I thought it is just the derivative of $e^{t^4}$, but it is wrong

can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Assume there is some function $F(u)$ for which $F'(u) = \mathrm e^{u^4}$.

Then, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus
$$\int_x^{x^2} \mathrm e^{t^4}~\mathrm dt = \left[F(t)\right]_x^{x^2} = F(x^2)-F(x).$$

Using the chain rule to differentiate $F(x^2)-F(x)$ w.r.t. $x$ gives
$$2xF'(x^2)-F'(x)$$
Recall that $F'(u)=\mathrm e^{u^4}$, and so
$$2xF'(x^2)-F'(x) = 2x\mathrm e^{x^8} - \mathrm e^{x^4}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $G(t)$ be the anti-derivative of $e^{t^4}$, then the integral is equal to
$$G(x^2)-G(x)$$
Differentiating with respect to $x$ here gives
$$2xG'(x^2)-G'(x)=2xe^{x^8}-e^{x^4}$$

It may be worth looking into Liebniz' integral rule for problems like this. It states
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)\,dt=f(x,b(x))\cdot b'(x)-f(x,a(x))\cdot a'(x)+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,t)\,dt$$